# Topnav gets messed up by border-right

Tags: html, css

Alright I am trying to make a header that is separated with a line between the links. Now I use border-right but then I mess up the 100%. I changed the width to 19% per link but then I don't fill up the entire 100%. I tried outline, but there seems no way to put the outline on the right side only. I am sure that I am not the first one to encounter this problem. What is the best solution?

```css
a {
 color: black;
}
#logoDiv {
 padding: 35px 0 35px 35px;
 background-color: #999;
}
#topNavUl {
 height: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#topNavUl li {
 height: 100%;
 width: 19%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

#topNavUl .notLast{
 border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="topNavDiv">
  <ul id="topNavUl">
   <a href="index.html"><li class="notLast">Home</li></a>
   <a href="Clients.html"><li class="notLast">Clients</li></a>
   <a href="Projects.html"><li class="notLast">Projects</li></a>
   <a href="Coworkers.html"><li class="notLast">Coworkers</li></a>
   <a href="Contact.html"><li id="lastTopNavLi">Contact</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rjw0o9he/ Add box-sizing: border-box, so, border will be included in element width... P.S. No need for additional classes inside list, you can target last element easier, e.g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: It's not clear what is wrong, from your snippet the links are appearing how you describe, and the total width is 100%.

I would advise you include swap your `<a>` and `<li>` tags round